# Cannot cast a System.Type to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a n-tier business application project incorporating C#/VB.NET and am having issues getting an update method to communicate between layers. In my data layer that is closest to my database, I have a GetByID() method that finds an employee based on their ID within the database, and places in a dictionary their title, first name etc as well as the entity as a whole (serialized).

In the next layer up (businessuser), I am trying to set its private members to the results of the businessuser GetByID() method that calls the data layers GetByID() method. It is here where I am trying to set my private member

```
_entity = (byte[])retDict["entity"];
```

Which gives me the error cannot implicitly type byte[] to System.Type since _entity is a Type.

The presentation layer done in VB, passes an employeeID via a listview selection value, which is then in turn passed down to the user layer and to the data layer.

Here is the EmployeeBusinessData layer GetByID() code:

```
public byte[] GetByID(int empid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Object> retDict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

        try
        {
            HelpDeskDBEntities dbContext = new HelpDeskDBEntities();
            dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Employee EmployeeEntity = dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeID == empid);

            if (EmployeeEntity != null)
            {
                retDict["title"] = EmployeeEntity.Title;
                retDict["firstname"] = EmployeeEntity.FirstName;
                retDict["lastname"] = EmployeeEntity.LastName;
                retDict["phoneno"] = EmployeeEntity.PhoneNo;
                retDict["email"] = EmployeeEntity.Email;
                retDict["departmentid"] = EmployeeEntity.DepartmentID;
                retDict["employeeid"] = EmployeeEntity.EmployeeID;
                retDict["entity"] = Serializer(EmployeeEntity, true);
            }
            else
            {
                retDict["error"] = "Employee not found!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeBusinessData", "GetByID");
        }
        return Serializer(retDict);
    }
```

And the EmployeeBusinessUser layer GetById():

```
public byte[] GetByID(int empid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Object> retDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try
        {
            EmployeeBusinessData empData = new EmployeeBusinessData();
            retDict = (Dictionary<string, Object>)Deserializer(empData.GetByID(empid));

            _employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(retDict["employeeid"]);
            _title = Convert.ToString(retDict["title"]);
            _firstName = Convert.ToString(retDict["firstname"]);
            _lastName = Convert.ToString(retDict["lastname"]);
            _phoneNo = Convert.ToString(retDict["phoneno"]);
            _email = Convert.ToString(retDict["email"]);
            _departmentID = Convert.ToInt32(retDict["departmentid"]);
            _entity = (byte[])retDict["entity"];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeUserData", "GetByID");
        }
        return Serializer(retDict);
    }
```

Here is the Serializer method code as well, it's the same in both class .dlls:

```
public static byte[] Serializer(Object inObject, bool bIsEntity = false)
    {
        byte[] ByteArrayObject;

        if (bIsEntity) //If the entity uses DataContractSerializer
        {
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(inObject.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(strm, inObject);
            ByteArrayObject = strm.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter frm = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
            frm.Serialize(strm, inObject);
            ByteArrayObject = strm.ToArray();
        }

        return ByteArrayObject;
    }

private Type _entity;
```

Two different types for Deserializer:

```
 public static Object Deserializer(byte[] ByteArrayIn, Type entityType)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ByteArrayIn);
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(entityType);
        Object returnObject = ser.ReadObject(stream);
        return returnObject;
    }
public static Object Deserializer(byte[] ByteArrayIn)
    {
        BinaryFormatter frm = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(ByteArrayIn);
        Object returnObject = frm.Deserialize(strm);
        return returnObject;
    }
```

How can I get retDict["entity"] to cast to a byte so I can assign it to _entity?

Comment: Since the value in question is being returned from your `Serializer` method, the details of that method are pretty important.

Comment: Post the definition for `_entity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
private Type _entity;
```

You probably want an Employee object instead, like so:

```
private Employee _entity;
```

Or if you want a variable that can hold any kind of object (or entity), then use the `object` type:

```
private object _entity;
```

A `Type` in .NET is the class that represents the type of a class, not a class itself.

So if I have a class like so:

```
public class Person
{
}
```

I can store it in an Person variable:

```
Person somePerson = new Person();
```

Or in an object variable:

```
object someObject = new Person();
```

But I can only store the type of an object in a `Type` variable:

```
Type someType = typeof(Person);
```

Or if you have an instance of an object you can get its type as follows:

```
Person somePerson = new Person();
Type typeOfSomePerson = somePerson.GetType();
```

But chances are you don't want the type at all.

**EDIT:**

I noticed you aren't deserializing twice in your question.  You are first serializing the entity and then separately serializing its fields.  I am not sure why you are serializing everything twice.  But at the very least you need to deserialize it twice.

So change this:

```
_entity = (byte[])retDict["entity"];
```

To this:

```
_entity = (Employee)Deserialize((byte[])retDict["entity"], typeof(Employee));
```

This is effectively saying, "Retrieve the serialized bytes of the Employee from the dictionary, deserialize the bytes into an Employee instance, and cast it as an Employee since the return type of the method is object."

But like I said, it seems you are doing each field twice.  You should only have to serialize the entity itself once, then deserialize the entity back again.  Unless there is something I am missing with your logic.

Comment: I made some edits to my answer, there are a few things you can probably change.